# Como calcular DigestValue en firma Digital

Tags: php, xml, firma-digital

Buen día amigos, aquí coloco mi ejemplo de firma XADES-EPES ENVELOPED donde no he podido encontrar como generar los DigestValue, no entiendo de donde sale el calculo ni en que instante de tiempo se hacen.

Me explico mejor, por ejemplo: ¿se colocan las etiquetas y en base a ellas se calcula? o se hace el calculo sin las etiquetas estar en el XML... gracias de antemano la ayuda.

Aquí coloco el ejemplo de XML, trabajo en PHP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: wagner pudiste resolver tu problema? me gusaria contactarme contigo tengo detalles similaes, es posible ?

Answer (score 0):

DigestValue contiene el resultado de aplicar el algoritmo hash a el (o los) recurso(s) transformado(s) codificado en base 64.

para PHP sirve este método:

$strcadena seria el fragmento xml a calcular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para calcular el digestvalue de la política de firma [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa por favor [answer]

Comment: lo probaré, gracias

Comment: Intenta poner el código en modo texto, cuando pones el código como imagen es más difícil de leer y menos accesible.